# trying to live stream from AWS/FMS to iphone (using HLS)

Tags: iphone, amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming, flash-media-server

I've set up an instance on Amazon AWS running Flash Media Server (FMS), which is broadcasting Live HTTP Streaming (HLS) following [these](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/FMS4.5EmbeddingLiveStream.html) instructions, so I know I'm steaming using the right streaming format for iPhone.

Further, using the same instructions i've confirmed that the server is up and running and i've successfully set up a flash client to read its HDS stream (HTTP Dynamic Stream for flash devices).

I wrote this iphone client code to play the stream (stolen from a [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tag/mpmovieplayercontroller/) that makes it work with a local video file.. that worked for me too):

```
@implementation BigBuckBunnyViewController

-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dstvrton8xbej.cloudfront.net/hls-live/livepkgr/_definst_/liveevent/livestream.m3u8"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerContoller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:streamURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerContoller];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerContoller.view];
    moviePlayerContoller.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerContoller play];

}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete: (NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [moviePlayerController release];

}
```

but i get this error msg when i compile the code onto my ipad:

```
2012-07-13 17:45:20.513 BigBuckBunny[3714:607] -[BigBuckBunnyViewController moviePlaybackComplete]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21050080
2012-07-13 17:45:20.524 BigBuckBunny[3714:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BigBuckBunnyViewController moviePlaybackComplete]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21050080'
```

from Mac [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSInvalidArgumentException) *NSInvalidArgumentException* happens when you pass an invalid argument to a method, such as a nil pointer where a non-nil object is required. Any ideas folks?

Comment: more on this.. I realized that by running this on an iPad/iPhone 5.1 simulator, it works.. but if i run it on a physical iPad version 4.3.3, it crashes with the said error message (interestingly, if I put an incorrect URL as a string, then the 5.1 versions crash with the exact same message.. my hypothesis is that I must ensure that the stream has fully loaded first before actually playing it on versions < 5.1).. i'll keep on digging since no one said anything yet here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple.. basically it's a syntax error (lol).. add ':' after moviePlaybackComplete

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification   
                                           object:moviePlayerContoller];
```