# Can android directly play Dynamic HTTP streaming using flash manifest file (.f4m)

Tags: android, http, live-streaming

I'm trying to make an app that plays live http streaming on android (i already did the same in [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473381/trying-to-live-stream-from-aws-fms-to-iphone-using-hls)). The Android official tutorial shows a sample [code](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) on how to do http live streaming, which i followed:

```
public class liveStream extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button streamButton;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_stream);

        streamButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.streamButton);
        streamButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_live_stream, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {       
        String url = "http://d2233avv69kunu.cloudfront.net/hds-live/livepkgr/_definst_/liveevent/livestream.f4m"; 
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

thing is I keep on getting an IOException when i try to prepare the player.. I did some research and it appears that I will need to play this off a flash client from my android? If that's so, how can I play live http streaming directly without the third party flash player? Similar to [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473381/trying-to-live-stream-from-aws-fms-to-iphone-using-hls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android doesn't support flash manifest file (.f4m) live streaming.

[Android supported format for streaming](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: What is the solution then? Is there any library/decoder to use in order to play .f4m streams?

Answer (score 0):

Most android devices from 2.3 on natively support Apple's HLS in some form or another . There are some devices where you'll need to use httplive://.../playlist.m3u8 instead up http://, but as far as I can tell, most devices support an m3u8 URL with just http, especially once you get past Android 3.0